# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' - How can I fix this when using Selenium with Spyder?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, anaconda, spyder

I have added the mentioned python package in Spyder(Anaconda) yet am seeing this error. Not sure what am doing wrong here.

```
import time
import random
import urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

The image is the error am getting when I try and run this, am not sure what am missing here. Have checked it in the `!pip list` I could see the `webdriver-manager` in the list. Please help me with this.

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/dinez/.spyder-py3/scrapping_db/level_scrapping_rotationalIP1.py', wdir='C:/Users/dinez/.spyder-py3/scrapping_db')
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)
 File c:\users\dinez\.spyder-py3\scrapping_db\level_scrapping_rotationalip1.py:6
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
```

I tried installing the package multiple times and nothing changed.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you installed the package for one version of python, but you are using a different version of python to run the code.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip --version`, and of this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Yeah!! You are right I have packages installed for a different version of the python. I have fixed that now. I didn't know there are two versions exist.